# How to find the measures that make a process martingale

Tags: measure-theory, martingales

Let $X_t$ a continuous stochastic process. My question is: How many probability measures $\mathbb{P}$  there exist that make $X$  a martingale? Is there any theorem to find them? my question is because I am not sure if there exist two measures $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ for wich $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{P}[X_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=X_s$ and $\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[X_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=X_s$ my guess is that it is true by Radom-Nykodim, but is there a way to find all of these measures?

Any help or advice is welcome, thank you very much!.

Comment: If $X_t$ is a constant process, there are quite some measures that will make it a martingale. For other cases, Girsanov theorem for example gives a construction of an *equivalent* change of measure that makes a process a martingale.